# Get the content of first cell in the column after onEdit() activeCell trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Spreadsheet with A1->J1 as TITLES ex.(ProductName, Price etc.). Now my script works but I have problems getting the content of the first row.

Lets say I add a new entry in A20, now the activeCell is A20, but how can I also get the A1 which is the header and print that with the activeCell? A1,B1,C1 all these are Titles, so when I edit B10 I should print B10+B1.

This is my Code:

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var editRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var editRow = editRange.getRow();
  var editCol = editRange.getColumn();
```

When I edit something I get numbers like A = 1, B =2, C = 3.
I just want the content of B1 not the column number. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the method `getValue()` to the top cell in the column. For example,

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var topCell = e.range.offset(1-e.range.rowStart, 0).getValue();
  Browser.msgBox(topCell);
}
```

This script makes use of the [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) to reduce the number of API calls to two (`offset` and `getValue`), the rest of information is extracted directly from the object. This is preferable, performance-wise, to a bunch of method calls like `getActiveSheet`, `getActiveRange`, `getRow`, `getColumn`...

Offset by `1-e.range.rowStart` means moving up from the edited cell to the first row.

Comment: Works like charm, i changed getA1Notation() to getValue() and my title is printed out. Thanks Alex you have helped me alot these few days :)

PS: Sorry for the grammar mistakes, ill use more time to double check my question for grammars next time!

Comment: I misunderstood the question. Edited it again to clarify, and edited the answer the answer accordingly.